# Load file from folder spring boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, classloader

Apache Maven 3.5.4

jdk-10.0.1

Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE

Win 10

I have images in the src/main/resources/images/ folder. When I run the application in the intelli J it works fine but when I create a jar of the application. It cannot find the image files. I tried followings neither worked. Any idea how I can retrieve the image files? Thanks.

```
    dogImageFile = new File("src/main/resources/images/dog.png");
    dogClick = new Image(dogImageFile.toURI().toString());


    dogImageFile = new File("\\images\\dog.png");
    dogClick = new Image(dogImageFile.toURI().toString());


    //Tried via @Value("classpath:dog.png") and ResourceLoader 

    //Also tried 

    dogClick= new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("src/main/resources/images/dog.png").toString(), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the version of java and the version of springboot. You need to care about the path of the compiled class files and resources files.

Comment: ```InputStream input = null;
  // read from the root folder
  input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/dog.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("static/xxx.pdf");
File targetFile = new File("xxx.pdf");
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(stream, targetFile);
```

Hi,you can read file in jar with this code!

Answer (score 0):

This does it.

```
dogClick = new Image("/images/dog.png");
```